# Unity ball friction either too much or not enough

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i am making a simple Golf game, when trying to replicate the balls movement i have noticed that on slopes the ball functions very oddly, it either never stops or stops too quickly and when travelling down slopes will reach a very slow terminal velocity quickly (ie it stops accelerating down slopes). So it either doesnt deaccelerate enough going up a slope or accelerates too slowly going down a slope.

I have been messing about with angular and static Friction of both the ball and the surface to see if that changes it at all and i have also been changing the friction combine of the surface and the ball to see if that makes any difference and so far haven't had any luck.

Is this a common issue with Unity because i haven't been able to find any other questions about it on here. If anyone could give me some advice on how to have my ball not roll forever but still accelerate when going down a slope that would be great

EDIT: The ball has a rigidbody with continous collision, then the course uses a mesh collider. Both however have attached physics materials

The ball is currently just a basic sphere from unity using a sphere collider, i havent tried changing the rigidbody about much yet other than mass. When the ball is hit i addforce to it, the slopes are an asset i have purchased that are perfectly smooth.

[image: RigidBody]
[image: Slope Physics]
[image: Flat Physics]
[image: Ball Physics]

Comment: A sphere collider is just a point collider, so it's likely your ball will not actually *spin*, is that correct ?

Comment: I believe it does because when i attach the camera to it, the camera starts orbiting the ball

Comment: I think that would be a whole other question. If it's a point collider, there's no reason at all the object would "tumble", spin on it's axis.  I suggest, replace the texture of the ball with any other texture at all, and, you will get more info about whether it is turning!  Again this is a whole other topic, and you (can and should) ask more questions about tumbling objects and ball physics!  Again, GameDev may be more useful.

Comment: Not worthy of a whole answer but suggest you check out: "WheelColliders".  Normally these are used for vehicles, but I think it might be suited to this case too.

Comment: FYI wheel colliders are completely unrelated to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolling object physics are indeed difficult in game engines.

As I mention in the comment for such questions it's necessary to know (a) what sort of **collider** and (b) what sort of object it is, since there are at least 4 major approaches to this problem.

But in general you usually have to manually add the "slowing down" function, in a sense representing air resistance.

For a moment set aside the collider choices, and imagine in the abstract you have a ball rolling along a flat plane. You've somehow started it moving at 2 m/s say.

There's really *no reason at all it will stop rolling* or slow down. Why would it? There's no air resistance in physX and what you "want" it to do in the game engine physics is keep rolling.

Thus what you do is add a script that, essentially, "slows it down a little" every frame. In pseudocode, something like

```
velocity = 0.99 * velocity
```

Note however that alternately, to "manually slow it down", you may have to simply add force to it.

The trick is you do that in the opposite direction to movement

```
yourBalls.addForce( v.normalized * -1 * some small force )
```

(It's easy to think of that as basically "air resistance")

You usually also, simply, just **add a top speed**. In this way on downslopes it won't just get "infinitely fast"

```
if (v.magnitude > 3.0) v = v.normalized * 3.0
```

That's basically how you make objects roll around on hilly surfaces.

Note that you basically should not fool with the friction settings in anyway, it's really not relevant in most cases.

Unfortunately there is a vast amount of detail but, I **feel your question is more asking for the "basic principles" - and there they are**!

Tip: it could be this question is more suited to the gameDev site, where "techniques" of game physics are QA'd.

Comment: Okay so im basically going about the whole thing wrong and should program in my own drag?

Comment: hi @ReeceHewitson - you've hit the nail on the head.  Very surprisingly in game physics, yes, it's one of those "very basic things nobody ever mentions!"  In a word you program in drag.

Comment: also @ReeceHewitson have a quick read about how vehicles (wheels) are done - you'll be surprised and informed!!  nothing "rotates", you just simulate the image rotating.  the "wheels" on any car game you've ever played are just points which move along the road surface. (imagine a GTA model, but, with four needles or pins in place of the sexy wheels and tires!)  good luck !

Comment: Thats actually really interesting, i had no idea! it's crazy how smart some of the techniques used in games are! i'll definitely have to have a read into it!

Comment: for the second part of the problem (rolling down hills), OP asked about making it roll faster. giving the ball a maximum velocity doesn't address this

Comment: @superexcellent12 - ?  Yes, it will speed up as it goes down the hill.  Due to gravity.  That's how the physics engine works as a baseline.  So that's done.  To test this, open unity, and tap two buttons to make a ball which rolls roll down a hill.  Then you have to do what it says in this answer.  (The only reason it "wasn't moving" for the OP was the OP incorrectly was touching the friction settings, which are irrelevant for a rolling ball and are not "friction" as you think of it in this situation.)